# Solr data import handler can't update but debug show it should

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

The problem is when we debug data import, it saids the values of a doc should change but then the value aren't on query.

This is the output of the dataimport.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "esp-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "status",
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "15",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "27",
    "Total Documents Processed": "1",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2018-03-12 13:24:41",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2018-03-12 13:24:42",
    "Optimized": "2018-03-12 13:24:42",
    "Time taken": "0:0:1.467"
  }
}
```

This is the output of the dataimpor-debug (modified to not show sensible data).

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1507
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "esp-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "full-import",
  "mode": "debug",
  "documents": [
    {
      .... Some fields with the values document should have ....
      "_version_": [
        1594749753815466000
      ],
      "_root_": [
        "E40004178"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "verbose-output": [
    "entity:esp",
    [
      "document#1",
      [
        "query",
        "Some query",
        "time-taken",
        "0:0:0.422",
        null,
        "----------- row #1-------------",
  ... Some more data ...
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "15",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "27",
    "Total Documents Processed": "1",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2018-03-12 13:24:41",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2018-03-12 13:24:42",
    "Optimized": "2018-03-12 13:24:42",
    "Time taken": "0:0:1.467"
  }
}
```

DIH on solrconfig.xml

```
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">esp-config.xml</str>
    </lst>   
</requestHandler>
```

Dataimport config file

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="TDatasource" driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="${ta.datasource.url}"
                user="${ta.datasource.user}" password="${ta.datasource.pass}"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="esp" pk="ID" transformer="TemplateTransformer"
                query="SELECT * FROM ESP e                                                                                                                                               
                WHERE ('${dataimporter.request.idP}' != '' AND to_char(e.id) = '${dataimporter.request.idP}') OR                                                                        
                ('${dataimporter.request.idP}' = '' AND ('${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false'                                                                                            
                OR e.VERSION > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'))">
...Some fields and child documents...
        </entity>
        <entity name="ab" pk="ID" transformer="TemplateTransformer"
                query="SELECT * FROM AB a                                                                                                                                         
                WHERE ('${dataimporter.request.idP}' != '' AND to_char(a.id) = '${dataimporter.request.idP}')                                                                           
                OR ('${dataimporter.request.idP}' = '' AND ('${dataimporter.request.clean}' != 'false' OR a.VERSION > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'))"> 
...Some other data for this but without child documents...
</entity>                                                                                                                                                                                     
    </document>
```

EDIT: Solr config autoCommit and autoSoftCommit

```
 <autoCommit>
   <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
 </autoCommit>
 <autoSoftCommit>
   <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
 </autoSoftCommit>
```

The problem is when search the same doc by ID, it returns the old version number instead new one 1594749753815466000 of the example.

The only solution by now is make a delete query of the document by ID and run index again.

We tried restarting all nodes because maybe the problem was on cache or something similar but the old values persists.

Solr version es 5.3.1

Comment: what is your operating system? Is upgrading solr to latest 7.x an option?

Comment: otherwise it sounds, like data import handler misconfiguration. Can you paste that?

Comment: Hello @D_K, yes it is if we can fix this problem, I'm going to edit post and past dih config.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but when you restart the Solr instance it will reset the cache. You can also try reloading the collection or cores from the admin page. If you're in SolrCloud, you should reuploading the schema to ZooKeeper using the zkclient script under cloud-scripts.

Comment: Also tried reloading of collections and cores. Why should I reload schema info if is doesn't change?

Comment: @MatìasFernàndez what sort of autocommit settings do you have?

Comment: and also, do you see any errors in the log?

Comment: Any error can be seen, the only thing I see es debug with the information I show in the post.

Comment: @MatìasFernàndez can you post the <autoCommit> and <autoSoftCommit> sections of solrconfig.xml ?

Comment: Sure @D_K, there is

Comment: @MatìasFernàndez this -1 for soft commit -- means commit asap? How did you figure out this value?

Comment: It is default config.